# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Request without an ID) error when trying to pass a params to a controller from a button press

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Edit: I finished renaming all of requests to assignments in the project and few issues surfaced as a result. I'll come back here with an update later after I deal with those issues, just need to take a break for now.  Thanks for all help so far.

Just a simple question, I'm fairly new to Rails on Ruby and barely understand how routing works. Version is 5.1.1.2.

I want to have a button create a new Active Record object when an user clicks on a button to confirm s/he accepted a request.  What I'm trying to do is have the button look up that current request by its id then create a new Contract record using that id as a foreign key. I keep getting ActiveRecord NotFound error and suspect that the code in routes.rb and button is wrong. I've tested the models themselves and they work in rails console by running user.accept(request) and user.decline(request) that's in user.rb. The issue is trying to get the button to do the same action.

partial for _accept button

```
<%= form_with model: current_user.active_contracts.build, local: true do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field :request_id, @request %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Accept", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#home'

    devise_for :users,
                    path: '',
            path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', edit: 'profile', sign_up: 'registration'},
            controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks', registrations: 'registrations'}

  resources :users
  resources :contracts, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :requests, except: [:edit] do
    member do
      get 'title'
      get 'dateandtime'
      get 'description'
      get 'location'
    end
  end

end
```

contract_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @request = Request.find(params[:id])
    current_user.accept(request)
    redirect_to request
  end

  def destroy
    @request = Request.find(params[:id]).accepted
    current_user.decline(request)
    redirect_to request
  end
```

Comment: I think you need to change `hidden_field :request_id, @request` to `hidden_field :request_id, @request.id`. And then in your `ContractController` change `@request = Request.find(params[:id])` to `@request = Request.find(params[: request_id])`.

Comment: Tried that, got different error. ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):

Comment: Do you set `@request` variable in the action that renders `_accept` button partial?

Comment: No, didn't, thought it didn't need to be since the partial is inside the nested request.each.

Comment: @fshenouda can you please share the code for rendering partial? Probably, you have to implement @fanta solution but use `request.id` instead of `@request.id`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what request is, but perhaps you need to change:

```
current_user.accept(request) -> @current_user.accept(@request)
```

Otherwise you should 
1. check that you are in fact getting the right param id by printing out params in the create method. `puts(params.inspect)`

Then you could also print out your Requests with `puts(Request.all.inspect)` to show you that you actually created that request you are looking for and it matches your id.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the router; it's your controller code.

Name your variable something else - the `request` method is going to be pulling from `ActionDispatch` and will return the complete HTTP request as enriched by the stack that got it down to your controller. That's why you'd need to change `current_user.accept(request)` to `current_user.accept(@request)` at a minimum - ruby isn't going to automatically generate the accessor method alias for your instance variable.

That said, I'd strongly encourage you to avoid using `request` or `@request` in a controller since those are effectively reserved words. You'd at least shadow some of the magic that's behind the scenes, and that'll invariably cause some sort of even harder to debug scoping issue in the future. Names like `pending_request` or `contract_request` or similar would be easier and not collide. If you used `contract_request` as the name, you'd write something like this:

```
def create
   @contract_request = Request.find(params[:id])
   current_user.accept(@contract_request)
   redirect_to @contract_request
 end

 def destroy
   @contract_request = Request.find(params[:id]).accepted
   current_user.decline(@contract_request)
   redirect_to @contract_request
 end
```

Which would, provided there are no other errors and you've updated the variables to match in the view and so on, fix your issue.

Comment: I tried that, still getting errors, I'll edit my post to add more info and code, hang on.